# Ambiguous constructor between list<string> and string

Tags: c++, constructor

In the following code, the compiler gives me an error when I try to pass a list to the constructor:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>


class MyClass {
    std::list<std::string> strings;

public:
    void disp() {
        for (auto &str : strings)
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass(std::string const &str)
        : strings({str}) {}

    MyClass(std::list<std::string> const &strlist)
        : strings(strlist) {}
};


int main ()
{
    // Compiles well:
    MyClass c1("azerty");
    c1.disp();

    // Compilation error, "call to constructor of 'MyClass' is ambiguous":
    MyClass c2({"azerty", "qwerty"});
    c2.disp();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to add `explicit` to the constructors' declarations, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: `MyClass c2({{"azerty"}, {"qwerty"}});` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: yes it's working, but why do i have to add extra braces? Is there a way to remove them, in order to improve readabilty?

Comment: Because [std::string's 9th constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has an initializer list.

Comment: @Gill Wrong constructor. That one isn't a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `string` has this constructor:

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

which `{"azerty", "qwerty"}` is an unfortunate match for because `const char*` is, in fact, an input iterator... even if the two arguments aren't intended to be iterators and aren't  iterators into the same container.

One solution would be to just provide a single constructor that takes an initializer list and just use that one:

```
MyClass(std::initializer_list<std::string> il)
    : strings(il.begin(), il.end())
{ }
```

Comment: Indeed, with 3 strings, there's no ambiguity. But my solution to add a `MyClass(const char *)` let me use it like this : `MyClass c1("foobar");` . It's a detail, but it improves readability when there are many objects to construct, almost all with only one string.

Comment: @yolenoyer I'd suggest a `MyClass(string )` and a `MyClass(initializer_list<string> )` if you want to go that route.

Comment: Thanks, it works like this! Even if don't understand exactly all the subtilities, especially about the `initializer_list` class... I will look at the doc later, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid is this ambiguous call is to do in this way,

```
     std::list<std::string> strList{"azerty", "qwerty"};
     MyClass c2(strList);
```

instead of

```
     MyClass c2({"azerty", "qwerty"});
```

Answer (score 0):

As people say in comments, it's because one of the `std::string`'s constructor overloads has an initializer list.

It's possible to fix it by adding additionnal braces:

```
MyClass c2({{"azerty"}, {"qwerty"}});
```

As I was looking for readability, I found a workaround by changing the string constructor by this one:

```
 MyClass(const char *str) : strings({str}) {}
```

Now I can do both of these constructs:

```
MyClass c1("foobar");
MyClass c2({"azerty", "qwerty"});
```